# Are there any performance issues when pushing objects to $scope.array versus var x = [ ] in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I often need to do things like this:

```
$scope.my_array = [];
var obj;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj = {};
    obj.item1 = data.something;
    obj.item2 = data.somethingElse;
    $scope.my_array.push(obj);
}
```

Is this less performant than doing the following:

```
var my_array = [];
var obj;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj = {};
    obj.item1 = data.something;
    obj.item2 = data.somethingElse;
    my_array.push(obj);
}

$scope.my_array = my_array;
```

My suspicion is that the first version may cause the digest cycle to be run each time an object is pushed into the array, whereas in the 2nd version it won't. Is this correct? Basically, what is the best way to do the above?

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: Have a look at [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/) - you can quickly setup a test yourself and look at comparisons.  I'm willing to bet somebody else has already tested this.  But no, there won't be any difference in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, at least for IE8.

$scope is a special object which look in parent scope when properties are not found. This means it has sme more internal mechanics than a normal javascript object that you declare.

I did had the same problem and got better performance on IE8 (1s to load against like 5s) when processing some data outside of $scope object. This is probably because of the way the $scope object is built.

However the digest cycle isn't trigger on each change i'm sure of it. But it can get some inner mechanics going on each time you change a value in maybe.

But i only saw a difference in IE8. So maybe the $scope object rely on something like a native javascript Linked List that has really poor performance in IE8.

Comment: Surely that would only be true if it had to look up the prototype chain to find a property? Since the array property is a property on the `$scope` object itself in this example, no prototype traversal is required to evaluate the `$scope.my_array` expression.

Comment: Still I got the issue with a property stored in the scope and not in his parent. As i said, the problem was only in IE8.